# Cash-Dom in not working while converting HTML to NextJs App

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cash-dom

I have a website where I have used Cash-Dom ( [Cash-Dom Repo. Link](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/cash) ). Now I am trying to convert the HTML website in NextJs. But showing me below errors

[image: Front End Error ScreenShot]
[image: Terminal Error]
[image: Cash-Dom js]

Comment: Can you show how you're using `cash-dom` in `_app.js `?

Comment: @juliomalves
 **_app.js** -> https://prnt.sc/1ugjws3
**global.js** -> https://prnt.sc/1ugkalz
**bootstrap** -> https://prnt.sc/1ugkg95

and let me if there's a correct way to use Cash-Dom in Nextjs or reactjs

Comment: `cash-dom` uses browser APIs so you'll have to import it on the client-side only. See [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780) for options on how to do it.

Comment: @juliomalves can you explain using my codes and file as a reference so I can understand it better.