# Next js dynamic imports with object destucturing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

> import { UDFCompatibleDatafeed } from
> "./datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed.js";

I need to convert the above import to the next js dynamic import. So I tried this way

```
const UDFCompatibleDatafeed = dynamic(() => import("./datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed.js").UDFCompatibleDatafeed);
```

UDFCompatibleDatafeed is a javascript class.

I am getting an error

> TypeError: UDFCompatibleDatafeed is not a constructor

Seems this is not importing correctly.

How do I fix this?

Comment: if it is a named export do this `import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.UDFCompatibleDatafeed )`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Can I add ssr false option to import as well?

Comment: Yes. `  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }` [https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import]

Comment: I tried this `const widget = dynamic(() => import("./charting_library/charting_library").then((mod) => mod.widget),{ssr:false});` @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV seems this is not the correct implementation

Comment: _"UDFCompatibleDatafeed is a javascript class"_ - Is it a React component too? `next/dynamic` should only be used to dynamically import React components. To dynamically import regular JS modules uses regular dynamic import as described in [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096260/webpack-why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined-in-next-js-when-i/66100185#66100185).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
const UDFCompatibleDatafeed = dynamic(
  () => import("./datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed.js")
  .then(m => m.UDFCompatibleDatafeed)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. How does this work? Are you still importing all the other components within ```udf-compatible-datafeed.js``` into your bundle?