# Next js named imports with no SSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I need to convert this line to next.js dynamic import and also without **SSR**

```
import { widget } from "./charting_library/charting_library";
```

I have tried this one

```
const widget = dynamic(() => import("./charting_library/charting_library").then((mod) => mod.widget), {
    ssr: false
});
```

This seems not the correct way and also charting_libray.js file is a compiled js file in a previous project.

[image]

Is the problem is my importing method or the js file? If this is importing method how do I fix this?

Comment: Is `./charting_library/charting_library` a React component? `next/dynamic` is used to import React components only. For regular JavaScript libs just use the regular dynamic import as described in [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780).

Answer (score 0):

```
const { widget } = await import("./charting_library/charting_library")
```

Maybe something along those lines might work? As for the SSR side I am not sure if you would need to execute it within a useEffect.