# Is there a way to use the screenfull javascript library within the Nextjs framework?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fullscreen

I've been trying to use Dynamic Importing in Nextjs in order to use the screenfull library but it hasn't worked.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic"
import screenfull from 'screenfull';
const Screenfull = dynamic(()=>{return import("screenfull")},{})
```

Comment: [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#basic-usage) is used to dynamically import _React_ components. To import regular JavaScript libraries you can simply use dynamic `import`. See [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using dynamic imports incorrectly. The idea is that you can import part of a JS module inside of another piece of JS code, so you don't have to preload or load the entire library. An example might be doing a dynamic import after an async call.

Next has some [other great examples](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) of how to use this functionality in your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can create file in `@utils` folder with below code:

```js
import screenfull from 'screenfull';

export default screenfull
```

then in your component do something like so:

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const screenful = dynamic(() => import('../@utils/screenfull'))
```

Comment: Hey what is that? I don't know what a utils folder is

Comment: you can create it anywhere in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

The first question that comes to mind is what's the error you're getting?
There's no reason you shouldn't be able to import any library you've `installed` locally!
Did you actually install that package by running `npm install screenfull` on your terminal?

Comment: Yes! I did install screenfull locally. The errors I got were: "Module not found", "can't resolve" and "document is not defined"