# Dynamically importing non-component exports from a react library into next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a react app and a components library. Library uses webpack and compiled into umd and uses react and react-dom as externals. Now I want to use it with another project which has Next.js SSR.

I can import components using `next/dynamic` and they work fine. But lib also has **non-component** stuff like **breakpoints and colors** and when I try to import them inside SSR, it complains `ReferenceError: self is not defined`. Lib's compiled code has `self` keyword in it. So it seems whenever I try to import breakpoints, next try to run library code server-side and throws.

Cannot use `next/dynamic` with non-components as it's only for components. I tried conditional import by checking `process.browser` but failed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined when I import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780)?

Comment: @juliomalves Yep that worked. Actually I was trying to import things in different places. Instead, created one component (containing lib code) and imported it into the page using `dynamic`. My previous approach is somehow impossible to achieve as trying to import anything outside `dynamic` or `useEffect` causes trouble. Thanks!