# React/Next JS import custom library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Im trying to learn react and next js. I wanna use [this plugin](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/). I installed that with npm but i dont know how to import it.

How i'm gonna use npm installed packages in my code?

Here is the code...

```
import React from 'react';
import VirtualSelect from 'virtual-select-plugin';

function Options() {

    VirtualSelect.init({
        ele: '#sample-select',
        options: [
          { label: 'Options 1', value: '1' },
          { label: 'Options 2', value: '2' },
          { label: 'Options 3', value: '3' },
        ],
    });

  return <div className='container mx-auto lg:px-10 px-5 mt-10'>
    <h2>Options</h2>
    <div>
        <div>
            <h3>Genre</h3>
            <div id="sample-select"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Year</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Seasons</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
}

export default Options;
```

error message:

```
./components/Options.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'virtual-select-plugin'
  1 | import React from 'react';
> 2 | import VirtualSelect from 'virtual-select-plugin';
  3 | 
  4 | function Options() {
  5 | 

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Comment: [The project's target is es5](https://github.com/sa-si-dev/virtual-select/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L14), so it's likely that it doesn't support being imported, using require or import.

Comment: soo how i can use it?

Comment: It looks like it adds `VirtualSelect` to the global object. So using `VirtualSelect` as-is should be fine.

Comment: Server Error

ReferenceError: VirtualSelect is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

components\Options.js (5:4) @ Options

  3 | function Options() {
  4 | 
> 5 |     VirtualSelect.init({
    |    ^
  6 |         ele: '#sample-select',
  7 |         options: [
  8 |           { label: 'Options 1', value: '1' },

Comment: I'm getting error if i remove the import

Comment: Maybe you need to be more specific? `window.VirtualSelect`? Also make sure that you're including the script in the public HTML page. https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=import-files

Comment: if i add the window.VirtualSelect, im getting error again.

Comment: Server Error

ReferenceError: window is not defined
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

components\Options.js (5:4) @ Options

  3 | function Options() {
  4 | 
> 5 |     window.VirtualSelect.init({
    |    ^
  6 |         ele: '#sample-select',
  7 |         options: [
  8 |           { label: 'Options 1', value: '1' },

Comment: btw, here is no html file in public folder

Comment: There should be. How did you make your react project? How does the react load onto the page?

Comment: i created a next js project with ```npx create-next-app@latest``` and it doesn't give me a html file in public folder. Just a favicon and vercel.svg file

Comment: Go through [this tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css). Since `VirtualSelect` needs to be treated as a static asset

Comment: For the `Module not found` error, make sure you have installed the package correctly, i.e. `npm i virtual-select-plugin`. For the `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error, see [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined when I import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096260/why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined-when-i-import-a-client-side).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- optional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.css">
<script src="node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.js"></script>
```

This is from the docs of virtual-select-plugins

[Reference](https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=get-started)

and you said you're using next js there is a scripttag in Nextjs Put it on your whole application _app.js in pages

[_app.js Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

I suggest read the docs

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do that
first option is to add your script tag in the public html page
second option is to install react helemet package for adding an element  of the head of component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

or you can simply use this package to create a virtual select in react https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-virtualized

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this simply by npm install.

Install the required package.

`$ npm i virtual-select-plugin`

Then you can see virtual-select-plugin module is added to dependencies. Look at package.json.

```
{
   "dependencies":{
     ...
    "virtual-select-plugin": "^1.0.29",
    ...

   }
}
```