# Next.js How can I initialise a module in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I am new to Next.JS and having a hard time adjusting myself to it. Especially around initializing an imported module in my `useEffect()`, as the module uses `window` which ssr cannot handle. Since it is not a component, I am not using the dynamic() here.

What I want to do is execute functions in the imported module, however it is giving me `var.func is not a function` error. I have tried several combinations, but none of them worked.

My attempt 1 - Use the variable which imported the module.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const runInit = async () => {
    const a = await import('MODULE_PATH')

    try {
      await a.init();
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
  runInit()
},[]);
```

My attempt 2 - Store the imported module in a state.

```js
const [mod, setMod] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  const runInit = async () => {
    const a = await import('MODULE_PATH')
    setMod(a)
    try {
      await mod.init();
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
  runInit()
},[]);
```

I also tried to set `let m = new a` but it did not work either. Can anyone please help me with calling functions in the imported module?

Comment: Is the module you're trying to import controlled by yourself, or a third-party library? As an alternative to your approach you could import it as usual at the top of the file, and then dynamically import that component using `next/dynamic` with `{ ssr: false }`. See the second approach in [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined when I import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780).

Answer (score 0):

I am new too. But I am using like below for sticky header

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const Navbar = () => {
    const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);
    const [shadow, setShadow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
            const handleShadow = () => {
                if (window.scrollY >= 90) {
                    setShadow(true);
                } else {
                    setShadow(false);
                }
            };
            window.addEventListener('scroll', handleShadow);
        }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, my goal is to run third party module in useEffect. Maybe my fundamental understanding of use of module in Next.js is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May you explain why you need to import the module inside the function block?
As the document said at the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import 
`import declarations can only be present in modules, and only at the top-level (i.e. not inside blocks, functions, etc.).` 
So it is not possible to import modules inside blocks or functions.

### Edit:

You can import your module at the top of your document and use it inside component or function like:

```js
import useRouter from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';
export const example = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function example(){
      if(router.query.id === 1){
        alert(1);
    };
    example();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Unfortunately, the module I use includes `window` and since I am using Next.js (server side rendering), it results in error. That is the reason I put it in the useEffect() to run it afterwards.
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: @knobutan It's a pleasure to help. Let's try importing your module at the top of your document, then call it in the useEffect(). `import Example from example`. `const a = new Example`. I hope it works.