# Bouncer.js in NextJS React is Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Good Day.
Banging my head here and need a pair of fresh eyes...

I have a NextJS (10.0.6) app (React 17.0.1). I'm trying to incorporate [Bouncer.js](https://github.com/cferdinandi/bouncer) validation code.

Both the `bouncer.min.js` file and my init() file are being pulled into the correct page,

```
<script src="/static/bouncer.min.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/static/bouncerLoad.js" async=""></script>
</body>
```

which I believe is evident because I'm getting an Undefined error.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

ReferenceError: Bouncer is not defined
```

This is the content of my `bouncerLoad.js` file:

```
var validate = new Bouncer('contactform');
console.log("bouncer loaded");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use npm to install and import it?

Comment: tried that too to no avail. Should work the way I have it too. When I import it I get `ReferenceError: self is not defined`. I'm still having to add the bouncerLoad.js to get the init to fire.

`module.exports = require("formbouncerjs");`

Comment: Why are you using a script to load your custom code? Next.js is a React framework, use React code instead (call `new Bouncer()` inside a `useEffect`).

Comment: Same issue @juliomalves -- 
`import formbouncerjs from "formbouncerjs";`
`useEffect(() => {`
` new Bouncer()`
Still results in "ReferenceError: self is not defined"
`module.exports = require("formbouncerjs");`

Comment: If you're using npm to import `formbouncerjs` then you have to dynamically import it inside the `useEffect`. See [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined when I import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096260/why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined-when-i-import-a-client-side).