# NextJS: how to use window in custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

This errors raises on the server side, when NextJS tries to render the page. But you can use `window` in the `useEffect` hook as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app).

My question is how to create a custom hook. I tried to something like that:

```js
export const useEventListener = (
    target: EventTarget, event: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, trigger = true,
): void => {
    useEffect(() => {
        target.addEventListener(event, listener);
        trigger && target.dispatchEvent(new Event(event));
        return () => target.removeEventListener(event, listener);
    });
};
```

The `window` here is used in `useEffect`. But I got the error, because when I call

```
useEventListener(window, 'scroll', () => {...});
```

NextJS do not recognize it.

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that solution is the best, but instead of `window` you can use `globalThis` which is equal to `window` on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

You're still getting the same error because `window` will still not be defined on the server when you call `useEventListener(window, 'scroll', () => {...});`. You should only reference `window` when inside the `useEffect`'s callback.

For example, you could modify your existing custom hook to default to `window` if no `target` is defined.

```js
export const useEventListener = (
    target: EventTarget, 
    event: string, 
    listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, 
    trigger = true
): void => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const t = target || window
        t.addEventListener(event, listener);
        trigger && t.dispatchEvent(new Event(event));
        return () => t.removeEventListener(event, listener);
    });
};
```

Then you could call the hook like:

```js
useEventListener(undefined, 'scroll', () => {...});
```

You could even remove the `target` param from the hook and always use `window` to make the usage and syntax simpler.

Comment: You forgot deps for useEffect. There is almost no use-cases for useEffect without deps.

Comment: @DTXqueque I didn't want to assume anything, as that's what OP had in his question. It's not related to his issue either way.