# how to remove the /[lang tag] from url using nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next

I want to remove the **/en** or the **/it** from the url. I don't want it to be explicit putting that in the url. i18next does it by default and I don't know how to remove it. I just want to make it in *background*.

[image: url]

Do I have to add any option to remove that or there's nothing I can do about?

My code is the following:

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
    },
  })

export default i18n
```

I import this in the page I want to translate

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MyComponent: ReactElement {
    const [isEnglish, setIsEnglish] = useState(true);
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsEnglish(!isEnglish);
        i18n.changeLanguage(!isEnglish ? 'en' : 'it');
    }
    return <>My stuff</>
 }
```

As I said it adds to my route /[language code]. Is there a way to remove it and just set it up in "background"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you use `use(Backend)`? I think that's the problem. You'd want to look at something like https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next, in order to correctly setup internationalization with server-side locale detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `next.config.js`.

```
i18n: {
  localeDetection: false,
}
```

this solves a problem for me.

Comment: If I do that it raises this error: > Specified i18n.locales should be an Array received undefined.    
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-i18n-config  .  If I add the "locales" array (also empty) it raises an error because "defaultLocale" is empty.  In the end I have to set a defaulktLocale and router.locale returns that one!

Answer (score 1):

**This solved my problem, hope it solves yours.**

- Use next `useRouter` to get the current active language:

```
import { useRouter } from  "next/router";
const router = useRouter();
const active_language = router.locale;
```

- Use `window` object to get the current full URL of your app:

```
const window_url = window.location.href;
```

**Note:**  Next.js executes code **first server-side**, then client-side (which includes the `window` object). there are many ways to achieve this, if you get "Window is not defined" read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app).

- Set your API URL based on the current active language,

assuming your default language is "en" :

```
let api_url = "";
if(active_language === "en") {
    api_url = `${window_url.substr(0, window_url.lastIndexOf("/"))}/`;
    console.log(window_url) // http://localhost:3000/shop
    console.log(api_url) // http://localhost:3000/
};
```

and your secondary language is "ar":

```
if(active_language === "ar") {
    api_url = window_url.substr(0, window_url.lastIndexOf("/") - 2);
    console.log(window_url) // http://localhost:3000/ar/shop
    console.log(api_url) // http://localhost:3000/
};
```

- Now your API URL is set to the same URL even if you switch the locale language:

```
fetch(`${api_url}/api/hello`);
```