# How to trace `window is not defined` errors at build time in NextJS apps?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, window

I'm trying to migrate an enterprise app (can't share code) from Create React App to NextJS (with TypeScript).

I've been able to replace the React Router with Next Routes/Pages, but I'm encountering this error message every time I try to build the app:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I've gone into the code and, everywhere that window appears, wrapped that code in an if check (`if(typeof window !== 'undefined')`). But I am still getting this error.

Is there any advice on how best to track down window references and make them NextJS compliant? Any "gotchas" that other folks have experienced?

I've gone into the code and, everywhere that window appears, wrapped that code in an if check (`if(typeof window !== 'undefined')`). But I am still getting this error.

Comment: Comment out things until the error goes away. I'm being serious.

Comment: This error is coming from Next trying to render content server side (where `window` is not defined because we are not in a browser JS environment). Check your error stack traces and see if these remaining issues are coming from third party libs. Some dependencies will only work when the components or pages are client-side rendered

Comment: @dylangrandmont I hadn't even considered third-party dependencies! I'll take a look now. Not sure the stack trace will be much help here since it keeps pointing me to calls within NextJS code itself, but maybe I just need to expand it more.

Comment: @dylangrandmont you were right! Turns out it's coming from `react-leaflet` (https://react-leaflet.js.org/). I'm gonna look into this other SO post about how to resolve it now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178127/next-js-with-react-leaflet-window-is-not-defined-when-refreshing-page.
Thanks for the advice @dylangrandmont!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using window.property somewhere in your code, you might want to place that piece of code inside a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@dylangrandmont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11714318/dylangrandmont) for his help in resolving this!

Turns out the error was coming from a dependency, `react-leaflet` (https://react-leaflet.js.org/). Once I noticed that, I found this other SO post about how to resolve it - [Next js with react-leaflet window is not defined when refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178127/next-js-with-react-leaflet-window-is-not-defined-when-refreshing-page)

Thanks for the advice [@dylangrandmont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11714318/dylangrandmont)!