# Next.js (React) + Phaser: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, phaser-framework

I'm trying to use `phaser` along with `ion-phaser/react` to build a page with a game in a Next.js app. This is my `pages/game.js` (using the React example from here https://github.com/proyecto26/ion-phaser):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Phaser from 'phaser'
import { IonPhaser } from '@ion-phaser/react'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    initialize: false,
    game: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      scene: {}
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { initialize, game } = this.state
    return (
      <IonPhaser game={game} initialize={initialize} />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Running `next dev` and visiting the page gives the following error:

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
init
file:///C:/git_projects/game/node_modules/phaser/src/device/OS.js (69:14)
Object.<anonymous>
file:///C:/git_projects/game/node_modules/phaser/src/device/OS.js (186:18)
Module._compile
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1063:30)
Object.Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1092:10)
Module.load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (928:32)
Function.Module._load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (769:14)
Module.require
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (952:19)
require
internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js (88:18)
Object.<anonymous>
file:///C:/git_projects/floam/node_modules/phaser/src/device/index.js (32:9)
Module._compile
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1063:30)
```

Why is `navigator` not defined?

These are my relevant package versions in `package.json`:

```
"next": "^9.5.5",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2",
"phaser": "^3.55.2",
"@ion-phaser/react": "^1.3.0",
```

Comment: You seem to be in the situation where importing the package crashes the server, which is the one described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679783/window-not-defined-or-document-not-defined-when-importing-module-in-next-js). Yours is older but the other answer is clearer about the underlying issue: a crash happening as soon as you import the module server-side.
I've crafted a complete answer covering all use situations there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556387/5513532

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["window not defined" or "document not defined" when importing module in Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679783/window-not-defined-or-document-not-defined-when-importing-module-in-next-js)

Answer (score 4):

Probably this package is not suitable for SSR. It seems like it calls `navigator` without checking availability of the browser api and it throws an error on server side.

If this package is React component then you can try to use [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) to import it (use `ssr: false` to exclude it from SSR):

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Phaser = dynamic(
  () => import('@ion-phaser/react'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

If this does not work then you need to use regular non-Next.js dynamic `import()` to import the whole module (in `useEffect` probably)

Answer (score 2):

I had to use useEffect, like so:

```
useEffect(async () => (window.Phaser = await import(`phaser`)), []);
```