# Implementing Owl carousel with NEXT.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I had done what has been told in the user guide of owl-carousel but I am getting this Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined.
I think there is a problem with the plugin or in config.next

please help me what should I do

Comment: The library you are using is probably not compatible with SSR. To use browser-only libraries do dynamic imports. Refer: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr Also refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55151041/11613622

Comment: Can you provide a code example of your component?

Answer (score 1):

Move the slider initialization code to componentDidMount() or useEffect if you are using hooks.