# Error in localstorage is not defined and window is not defined in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

my project is on nextjs. before return, I need localStorage or window. but it gives me the Error localStorage is not defined and window is not defined... I have checked other questions but there is no proper answer. Please someone can help me to fixes this issue. Here is code:

[image] [image]

```js
import moment from "moment";
import { useState } from "react";



export default function Clicked() {

    const [passed, setPassed] = useState(false)

    const click = () => {
        const currentTime =moment().format('HH:mm:ss');


        
        var endTime = moment().add(10, 'second').format('hh:mm:ss A')
        
        localStorage.setItem('currentTime', currentTime)
        localStorage.setItem('endTime', endTime)
        
        
        
        console.log(endTime)
        console.log(currentTime)
        
        
    }
    console.log(window)
    const currentTime = localStorage.getItem("currentTime");
    console.log('currentTime', currentTime)


    return(
        <>
        
            <button onClick={() => click()}>click</button>
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403018/16732460

Comment: No, I am using react hooks.

Comment: @ShahabKhan Just scroll that thread, it has answer for hooks too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403018/11613622 -- basically the (three) statements that you have written after the `click` function need to be moved to a `useEffect` hook. Alternatively  you can just check if `typeof window !== 'undefined'` before executing your client side code. That too is mentioned in that thread.

Comment: Yes, Thank you...