# Server Error ReferenceError: window is not defined in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js, clevertap

I'm trying to integrate `CleverTap` into my `Next.js` app. Followed the documentation [Web SDK Quick Start Guide](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/web-quickstart-guide) but facing issue:

> **Server Error ReferenceError: window is not defined in Next.js**

[image: Please have a look]

---

`_app.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import { Hydrate, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";

import nextI18NextConfig from "../next-i18next.config.js";

import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import "styles/globals.scss";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import SvgPageLoading from "components/color-icons/PageLoading";
// import { PageLoading } from "components/color-icons/";

import { DefaultSeo } from 'next-seo';
import SEO from 'next-seo.config';
import {cleverTap} from "utils/cleverTapHelper";

cleverTap.initialize('TEST-61c-a12');

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(
    () =>
      new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: {
            refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
            staleTime: Infinity,
          },
        },
      })
  );
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStart = () => {
      setIsAnimating(true);
    };
    const handleStop = () => {
      setIsAnimating(false);
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
    router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleStop);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
      router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleStop);
    };
  }, [router]);
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
        <DefaultSeo {...SEO} />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        {isAnimating && (
          <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center w-screen h-screen overflow-visible bg-white bg-opacity-80 z-overlay top-z-index">
            <SvgPageLoading />
          </div>
        )}
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

export default appWithTranslation(MyApp, nextI18NextConfig);
```

`cleverTapHelper.ts`

```
export const cleverTap = {
    initialize: function (accountId) {
        console.log('I see initialize req')
        window.clevertap = {event: [], profile: [], account: [], onUserLogin: [], notifications: []};
        window.clevertap.account.push({'id': accountId});
        (function () {
            var wzrk = document.createElement('script');
            wzrk.type = 'text/javascript';
            wzrk.async = true;
            wzrk.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net' : 'http://static.clevertap.com') + '/js/a.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(wzrk, s);
        })();
    },

    event: function (name, payload = {}) {
        console.log('I see event req')
        if (payload) {
            window.clevertap.event.push(name, payload);
        } else {
            window.clevertap.event.push(name);
        }

    },

    profile: function (payload) {
        console.log('I see profile req')
        window.clevertap.profile.push(payload);
    },

    logout: function () {
        console.log('I see logout req')
        window.clevertap.logout();
    }
};
```

`cleverTap.d.ts`

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        clevertap: any;
    }
}

export {};
```

---

**Window** object should not be `undefined` but getting undefined! What's going on?

Comment: Since NextJS renders components on the server-side, it cannot access the window object. You can turn off server-side rendering for the component you specify by doing dynamic imports. I just found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848309/10124281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because NextJS is trying to execute that function on the server because it uses SSR, and `window` is a browser object. Since the `window` object is available only in the browser (client-side), the server is unable to identify the `window` object, hence getting `undefined`. In order to fix this, you should make sure that any functions/components that contain client-side related code be executed only on the browser or client-side. One way is using hooks such as `useEffect` that run only after the component is mounted. Another way is to use lazy loading which pretty much does the same thing.

1. Using `useEffect` hook.
   In your `_app.tsx` component, add a new `useEffect` hook and move the initialization code into the newly created `useEffect` function.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  cleverTap.initialize('TEST-61c-a12');
},[])
```

2. Using lazy loading. (Dynamic import)
   Instead of directly importing the function, import it dynamically and set server-side rendering to `false`:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const cleverTap = dynamic(()=>{
  return import("utils/cleverTapHelper")
},
{ssr:false}
)

cleverTap.initialize('TEST-61c-a12');
```

Answer (score 0):

For TS folks struggling out there with clevertap and nextjs, install sdk and types:

```
npm i -S clevertap-web-sdk @types/clevertap-web-sdk
```

then, async import while initializing:

```
import CleverTap from 'clevertap-web-sdk/clevertap';
// ^^ this only imports types

let clevertap: CleverTap;

export const initClevertap = async (clevertapAccountID: string, region: string): Promise<void> => {
    clevertap = (await import('clevertap-web-sdk')).default;
    clevertap.init(clevertapAccountID, region);
    clevertap.privacy.push({ optOut: false });
    clevertap.privacy.push({ useIP: true });
    clevertap.setLogLevel(0);
    clevertap.spa = true;
};
```

PS: dynamic import didn't worked for me, looks like it's only for components and not libs