# Next.js typescript "window" in not defined

Tags: typescript, next.js

Hi I am declaring an audio context like this and it says window in undefined. I tried declaring **declare const window :any** above **window.Context** but the error's still there. Anyone know how I can solve this?

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext

export default function TestPage(){

   const audioContext = new AudioContext();

   return <>Hello</>
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next.js` runs server side. `window` is only available on client side. So you will have to wait until component is mounted, like this:

```
export default function TestPage(){

   const audioContext = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext;
audioContext.current = new AudioContext();

   },[]);


   return <>Hello</>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the server side rendering, so when nextjs is being rendered on the server the `window` doesn't exist yet, because `window` is only on the client.

What I usually do is to have some sort of function that is triggered in the client to initialize window:

(I assume that you're using reactjs because of the component format and fragment on the snippet)

```
export default function TestPage() {
   const [audioContext, setAudioContext] = useState<AudioContext | null>(null)
   useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const val = window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      setAudioContext(val)
      // or you can put your logic here without setting the state
    }

   }, [])

   useCallback(() => {
     if (audioContext !== null) {  
       const audioContext = new audioContext();
       // your other logic for audio context
     }

   }, [audioContext ])

   return <>Hello</>
}
```