# Next js window.matchMedia prefers-color-scheme window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, matchmedia

I am using React.js with Next.js, and I have the following problem. When the page is loaded, I have to set a variable which should tell me if user is using dark mode or not.

I did the following, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I had to set a value, because if I use window inside `useState` without using `useEffect`, it gives me problems with Next.js.

```js
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setDarkMode(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
  const modeMe = (e) => {
    setDarkMode(!!e.matches);
  }
  window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', modeMe);
  return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').removeListener(modeMe);
}, []);
```

or

```js
const useDeviceMode = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)
    const modeMe = e => { setDarkMode(!!e.matches); }
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', modeMe);
    return window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').removeListener(modeMe);
  }, []);
  return [darkMode, setDarkMode]
}

const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useDeviceMode();
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: What you did in the first code block seems correct. Next.js pre-renders all pages on the server, so any access to `window` should happen on the client-side only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this snippet—

```js
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

const modeMe = (e) => {
    setDarkMode(!!e.matches);
  };

useEffect(() => {
  const matchMedia = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  
  setDarkMode(matchMedia.matches);
  matchMedia.addEventListener("change", modeMe);

  return () => matchMedia.removeEventListener("change", modeMe);
}, []);
```

Even better, come up with this custom hook—

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const modeMe = (e) => {
    setDarkMode(!!e.matches);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

    setDarkMode(matchMedia.matches);
    matchMedia.addEventListener("change", modeMe);

    return () => matchMedia.removeEventListener("change", modeMe);
  }, []);

  return darkMode;
};
```