# Set window.innerWidth in useEffect in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem [using this custom hook](https://pastebin.com/W282K2sc) to obtain the window's width. In `Next.js`, when I use this hook in my code:

```
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  console.log(``, useWindowSize);
```

Initial value is `null`, until I change the window's size. How can I set up the initial value?

Comment: Could you please edit this question as to make it clearer that you are getting this error using Next.js? Maybe here you can find the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app

Answer (score 1):

**Answer specific to Next.js**

Since you are using Next.js `window` isn't defined until the code is run on the client side. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app) suggests, try setting an initial width on an `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => setWindowSize(window.innerWidth), [])
```

Observe the empty brackets meaning the hook will be executed once on every render, which in this case means once it renders on the client's side.

**Answer not specific to Next.js**

In your hook, initialize it to `window.innerWidth` instead of `null`.

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState<number>(window.innerWidth)
```

**Other observations**

Also, I would suggest you set up a listener for resize on a separate `useEffect` hook because the way it is right now the listener depends on `windowSize` changing before being attached. Take for example this `useIsVertical` hook:

```js
const useIsVertical = () => { 
   const [isVertical, setIsVertical] = useState(false) 
  
   const onResize = () => { 
     const height = window.innerHeight 
     const width = window.innerWidth 
  
     height > width ? setIsVertical(true) : setIsVertical(false) 
   } 
  
   useLayoutEffect(() => { 
     onResize() 
   }, []) 
  
   useLayoutEffect(() => { 
     window.addEventListener('resize', onResize) 
     return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize) 
   }, []) 
  
   return isVertical 
 }
```

Comment: When I put 
```
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState<number | null>(
    window.innerWidth
  );```

I get:
```ReferenceError: window is not defined```

Comment: I still have:ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Please, check the edited answer and see if it does solve your problem