# How to make date for input value in next.js using react-input-date-mask

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I tried `react-input-date-mask` to use the input mask for a date in my code like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactInputDateMask from 'react-input-date-mask';

export default function PartnersDetailsForm() {
const [feildsValue, setFeildsValue] = useState({
        name: "",
        lastName: "",
        birthDate: "",
    })
});

const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
   let changedValue;
   if (e.target.name === "CPF" || e.target.name === "birthDate" || e.target.name === "cell") {
     changedValue = e.target.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
   } else {
     changedValue = e.target.value;
   }
   setFeildsValue({ ...feildsValue, [e.target.name]: changedValue });
}

return (
        <>
           <ReactInputDateMask mask='DD/MM/YYYY' showMaskOnFocus={true} value={feildsValue.birthDate} onChange={(e) => {onChangeHandler(e)}} showMaskOnHover={true} />
        </>
)
```

which is quite similar to this `https://codesandbox.io/s/r2f5r?file=/src/App.js:148-185`.

But in my code the output is

[image]

Why am I getting a window error?

Comment: What is the version of `react-input-date-mask` that you are using?

Comment: I am using the 2.0.0 version of react-input-date-mask.

Comment: It seems `ReactInputDateMask` uses Web APIs that aren't accessible when Next.js pre-renders the page on the server. Try using `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false` to dynamically import `ReactInputDateMask` instead. See [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57848309/1870780).