# ReferenceError: window is not defined error in next's

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components

I wrote this code in next.js but I encountered an error. The error says "NextJS - ReferenceError: window is not defined". can you help me how can i fix it

```
function IconWeatherComponent({icon}) {
    
    let [svg, setSvg] = useState('');
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const setIcon = () => {
            if (icon === '01d') {
                setSvg('day.svg')
            }
            if (icon === '01n') {
                setSvg('night.svg')
            }
        setIcon();
    }, [icon])
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={`${window.location.origin}/weather-icons/${svg}`} width="70" height="70" alt=""/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default IconWeatherComponent
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)

Comment: Thinking on this further, do you really need to be accessing the window location? If these svg file are in the same project, you can import them directly into this component. That would be better unless for some reason you can't include those files in this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is not defined at build time, so it can't be accessed directly in your JSX. It is only defined in the browser. You will need to check for the location only at runtime, in a useEffect hook.

```
function IconWeatherComponent({icon}) {
    
    let [svg, setSvg] = useState('');
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const setIcon = () => {
            if (icon === '01d') {
                setSvg('day.svg')
            }
            if (icon === '01n') {
                setSvg('night.svg')
            }
        setIcon();
    }, [icon])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            setLocation(window.location.origin)
        }
    }, []
    
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={`${location}/weather-icons/${svg}`} width="70" height="70" alt=""/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default IconWeatherComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access window object but in this solution window is not define.
Add your code to a usseefect and save data to state.hope solve your problem

```
Usseefect (()=>{Setwindowlocation(window.location.origin)},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the accepted answer correct but slightly overkill, because it involves handling state in your component, and the image URL will be inconsistent while the component is mounting.

It is ok to use the `window` object directly in your render function, in this situation, I would rather rely on a `useMounted` utility:

```
const useMounted = () => {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState<boolean>()
    // effects run only client-side
    // so we can detect when the component is hydrated/mounted
    // @see https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        setMounted(true)
    }, [])
    return mounted
}

// in your component
const mounted = useMounted()
// render nothing server-side and during first render, or a placeholder
if (!mounted) return null
return (
        <div>
            <img src={`${window.location.origin}/weather-icons/${svg}`} width="70" height="70" alt=""/>
        </div>
    );
```

Also, you don't need an effect + state to compute a value derived from props, see the new ["You might not need an effect" section](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state) in React documentation.

More broadly, this "window not defined" error comes up in different shapes in Next.js, all vaguely related yet not exactly the same.

I've summarized all the possible situations in an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556387/5513532).