# Window and DOM loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it always true that `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired before `window.onload` event since most webpages are with images and stylesheets or can it happen the other way? I need to know whether `window.onload` always happen after the `DOMContentLoaded` event and what happens if the webpage doesn't have any stylesheets, images, and subframes?

**A window is said to be loaded only if DOM has finished loading.**

Is this statement true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

Comment: @Bruno Ely: I am not seeking the difference and I read the above question before posting mine. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** see [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194842/3403247) for more a in-depth explanation—in short, it *is* specified that `DOMContentLoaded` will always fire before `load`.

I̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶e̶i̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶r̶ ̶g̶u̶a̶r̶a̶n̶t̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶`̶l̶o̶a̶d̶`̶ ̶_̶a̶l̶w̶a̶y̶s̶_̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶`̶D̶O̶M̶C̶o̶n̶t̶e̶n̶t̶L̶o̶a̶d̶e̶d̶`̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶f̶a̶i̶r̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶u̶m̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶.  In order to finish loading the whole page, the browser needs to fully load the DOM first—and will p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y definitely fire `DOMContentLoaded` before firing `load` even if there are no resources waiting to be loaded.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> The **`DOMContentLoaded`** event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.
>
> A different event, `load`, should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end:event-domcontentloaded) published by WHATWG, specifies the order of actions that happen when the DOM has been parsed. It has 12 steps. Steps 4 and 7 deal with the events you ask about:

> 4) Queue a task to run the following substeps:
>
> 1. Fire an event named `DOMContentLoaded` at the Document object, with its bubbles attribute initialized to true.
> 2. Enable the client message queue of the ServiceWorkerContainer object whose associated service worker client is the Document object's relevant settings object.
>
> 5) Spin the event loop until the set of scripts that will execute as soon as possible and the list of scripts that will execute in order as soon as possible are empty.
>
> 6) Spin the event loop until there is nothing that delays the load event in the Document.
>
> 7) Queue a task to run the following substeps:
>
> 1. Set the current document readiness to "complete".
> 2. Load event: If the Document object's browsing context is non-null, then fire an event named `load` at the Document object's relevant global object, with legacy target override flag set.

Since queued tasks are guaranteed to run in the order they were queued, the order of these two events is guaranteed.

In fact, the `DOMContentedLoaded` event will already have been processed by step 5 and 6 ("spin the event loop") before `load` is added to the queue.

Comment: Nice!  Will edit my answer soon to link to yours since that’s better than the general assumption I make