# Is DOMContentLoaded and document.onload events are same?

Tags: javascript, events

**DOMContentLoaded**

```
document.addEventListner('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

})
```

**document.onload**

```
document.onload(function(){

});
```

Is DOMContentLoaded and document.onload events are same

Comment: what you are saying is done by window.onload, I am thinking about document.onload

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

Comment: There's no `document.onload` event at all.

Comment: @Omri Sorry that is difference..i checked then i created this stack question.

Comment: @Teemu What do you think what is the javascript alternative for  $(document).ready() then ?

Comment: JQuery uses `DOMContentLoaded` internally in `$(document).ready()` implementation.

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, Is there any reference which you can guide me ?

Comment: Just load the unminified jQuery source code, and check it yourself.

Comment: look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21155413/3729184)

Comment: @omri That Helped. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be useful for someone

source : [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events/21155413#21155413)

```
DOMContentLoaded==window.onDomReady()

Load==window.onLoad()
```

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside    $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object    Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included    inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire    page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

See: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

The syntaxe should be (as a comment pointed out) :

```
document.onload = function(){};
```

and I think it does only work when targeting an elemnt like so :

```
document.getElementById('image').onload = function(){};
```

It will assign the function to the onload handler.

Whereas

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){})
```

Waits for the DOM to be ready before triggering, meaning that images, iframes, ect... could not be loaded.