# document.ready & window.onload vs CSS Media Queries

Tags: javascript, css

While doing research on CSS and JS codes that run before the user sees the content, something was stuck to my mind. When exactly were CSS media queries were running? Which js and jquery function run first (document.onload, document.ready etc.)? When I did research on it I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) and  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events) questions which explain the difference between domcontentloaded, document.ready and window.onload functions. However, I could not figure out when exactly media queries in CSS run compared to these functions. So I checked it through JSFiddle in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yus47hf8/3/).

In HTML part I only wrote a div with and ID;

```
<div id="testDiv">
  Test Media Queries And JS Functions
</div>
```

In CSS there was only 1 media query that ran;

```
@media screen and (min-width:1px){
  #testDiv{
    color: black;
  }
}
```

And in JS part, there was different load functions

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").style.color = "blue";
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").style.color = "red";
});

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("testDiv").style.color = "yellow";
};
```

The CSS code and its effects were visible for a brief moment. And than the div was turning to blue when I ran the code. However, I encountered a strange problem. Only in Google Chrome New Tab (Not Incognito), the code ran as yellow which means window.onload was running last and in all other browsers and tabs shows the div as blue.

[Google Chrome Not Incognito Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUPEV.png)

[Google Chrome Incognito Tab and Safari New Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G2Ue.png)

First of all is this some kind of bug that I encountered or somehow is it intended to run like this?

Second of all, I could not find any documentation on when exactly media queries run compared to these functions.

If anyone has a link for documentation on CSS queries and their exact execution time, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: My computer is Macbook Pro 2020 13.3 with Intel Chip and I checked it in Google Chrome 3 application. A little side note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Second Answer First*

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events) You already familiar that if you use Javascript (that is not async or defer) then the `DOM` creation will wait for the JS to load. Since `JS` also modifies `CSS`, so `JS` will wait for the `CSSOM` to load, and in this way you got the answer that media queries runs earlier.

*Now First one*

**Basically**

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the `DOM` is created.

The jQuery `$(document).ready()` event is fired when the `DOM` is ready.

The `load` event is fired when the `DOM`, `CSSOM` and all other resources are loaded (jQuery library is one of them).

*In this case*

First `DOM` creation will wait for the `JS` to load when it is loaded then `DOM` is created, and `DOMContentLoaded` event fires at **first place** so `color:red` overrides `color:black` applied by media query.

Now `load` event is fired at ***second place*** because `JS` is already loaded and `DOM` and `CSSOM` is also loaded so `color:yellow` overrides `color:red`,

And `document.ready` event is fired at ***third place*** when DOM is ready so `color:blue` overrides `color:yellow`. and you see **color blue**.

**Important**

If you add an image just like [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/AamirSohailKmAs/u3q14oyt/1/) then you'll see that

First `DOM` creation will wait for the `JS` to load when it is loaded then `DOM` is created, and `DOMContentLoaded` event fires at **first place** so `color:red` overrides `color:black` applied by media query.

Now `document.ready` event is fired at ***Second place*** when DOM is ready so `color:blue` overrides `color:red`.

And `load` event is fired at ***Third place*** because `image` is not loaded when `DOM` was ready and so `color:yellow` overrides `color:blue` after image is loaded,