# WebComponent setter not triggered if defer is used

Tags: javascript, web-component

I recently noticed that a setter in a web component is not being called when you inject the webcomponent javascript file with a script tag where the `defer` attribute is used.
You can see the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/web-component-with-setter-1ij4o

Within the `script` tag of the `index.html`, I set the property `foobar` to "test". This should trigger the setter of the webcomponent, which should print the value "test" to the screen by an alert command. But this does not happen. If you delete the `defer` attribute, everything works as expected. Can you tell me why this is happening, and do you have a solution where the setter is being called without deleting the `defer` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your inline script is running before the deferred script.

You can solve this by either putting your inline script in a file and loading it with the defer attribute OR by putting the inline code inside an event listener to run after the 'DOMContentLoaded' event.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const wc = document.querySelector("custom-text");
  wc.foobar = "test";
});
```

Comment: This works for OPs question; but you might want to wait even longer for the ``load`` Event, with ``DOMContentLoaded`` assets might still be loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events