`function onload(){}` is not the same as `window.onload=function(){}` - the former doesn't fire on page load. Why?
Context: I'm trying to programmatically detect (via an injected script) if an arbitrary page (not coded by me) has a window.onload function set (via window.onload=foo, not addEventListener).
I thought that I could simply check if typeof window.onload === "function", but that is true for this case:
<script>
  function onload() {
    console.log('onload called'); // this is *not* triggered on page load
  }

  typeof window.onload === "function"; // is true
  window.onload === onload; // is`true`
  window.hasOwnProperty("onload"); // is`true`
</script>

And yet that function is not automatically called during page load. I've tested in latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.
I thought that would be ~equivalent to this:
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log('onload called'); // this *is* triggered on page load
  };
</script>

But it seems that's not the case. The browser is seems to have a setter (or something like that) which is triggered when explicitly assigning window.onload, versus the case where a global variable is implicitly accessible via the window object.
How can I robustly detect (via an injected script) whether an arbitrary page has an actual window.onload set (one that is triggered on page load, I mean), and not just e.g. a global function called onload?

You said "And yet that function is not automatically called during page load." That's because that function is NOT under window. I bet you'll get the same result if you completely delete this block. If that's the case, you're just detecting some kind of default window.onload() function which is inherently part of the page (and it's just replaced when you create your own). I would check what happens using other browsers.

You shoold prefer to use DOMContentLoaded event -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

People, please read the question more carefully, and please remove or explain the close vote. I'm very clearly not asking what event is most appropriate to use. As I said at the start, and reiterated at the end: How can I robustly detect whether an arbitrary page has an actual window.onload set  (one that is triggered on page load, I mean), and not just e.g. a global function called onload? I'll try to add a clarifying edit, but I'm not sure how I can be much more clear here.

@joe - your question was crystal clear to me from the first time I read it

document.body.onload is an alias for window.onload.
So, the following should output false


function onload() {
  console.log('does not fire on load');
}
console.log(window.onload === document.body.onload)



Whereas, using window.onload =, the following should output true (and also the console.log in the onload handler


window.onload = function onload() {
  console.log('does fire on load');
}
console.log(window.onload === document.body.onload)




Legendary. This works (tested in Firefox and Chrome). Thank you!
